Flutter font crashed
My font is "crashed". When i using FontWeight.normal font is good, but when i change to FontWeight.bold my font is crashed.
My main.dart
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    primaryColor: mainColor,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
      primary: mainColor,
      secondary: secondColor,
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyLarge: TextStyle(
        color: fontColor,
        fontFamily: "RedRose",
        fontVariations: const <FontVariation>[
          FontVariation('wght', 300),
          FontVariation('wdth', 150),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

And how i use this font:
ResponsiveText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  text: 'WERYFIKACJA DWUETAPOWA',
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .bodyLarge!
                      .copyWith(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

My ResponsiveText class:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveText extends StatelessWidget {
  ResponsiveText(
      {this.text = 'text',
      this.textAlign = TextAlign.left,
      this.style = const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
      super.key});

  String text;
  TextStyle style;
  TextAlign textAlign;

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      textAlign: textAlign,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: style,
      ),
    );
  }
}

And effect as screen:

I tried to download this font from other site and still this font is crashed.
